# Infinite loop not working properly in program

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, infinite-loop

This program uses a 2D array to record open and reserved rooms.The program displays the 2D array at start and after every change to the array. The index values represent room numbers and are displayed for open rooms.  Reserved rooms show the name of the person reserving the room. The program will keep on running until the user inputs a "Q".

Everything seems to work perfectly fine for me except for after going through the loop in the main method once, the programs stopped running even if the user did not input "Q". I've also tried doing it with while(true) but it is still not working. I really hope that someone can help me with this.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (in);
    out.print("Enter row size: ");
    int row = kb.nextInt();
    out.print("Enter column size: ");
    int col = kb.nextInt();
    kb.nextLine();
    String [][]rooms = roomInIt(row, col);
    printMatrix(rooms);
    String a="";


    for(;;)
    {
        out.print("Would you like to reserve or release a room? Type Q to exit ");
        a = kb.nextLine();

        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("reserve"))
        {
            out.print("How many rooms would you like to reserve? ");
            int num = kb.nextInt();
            reserveRooms(rooms, num);
        }
        else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("release"))
        {
            out.print("How many rooms would you like to release? ");
            int x = kb.nextInt();
            releaseRooms(rooms, x);
        }
        else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
            break;
    }
}

public static void printMatrix(String[][]rooms)
{

    for(int r=0; r<rooms.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<rooms[r].length; c++)
                out.print("["+r+","+c+"] "+rooms[r][c]+"\t");
            out.println();
        }
}

public static String[][] roomInIt(int row, int col)
{
    String [][]rooms = new String [row][col];
    for(int r=0; r<rooms.length; r++)
        for (int c=0; c<rooms[r].length; c++)
            rooms[r][c]="open";
    return rooms;
}

public static void reserveRooms(String [][]room, int num)
{

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {   
        out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = kb.nextLine();
        out.print("Enter the room number (row and column separated by a space) ");
        int r=kb.nextInt();
        int c=kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        while (r<0 || r>room.length || c<0 || c>room[r].length || !room[r][c].equals("open"))
        {
            out.print("Invalid room number. Enter another room number (row and column separated by a space) ");
            r=kb.nextInt();
            c=kb.nextInt();
            kb.nextLine();
        }
        room[r][c] = name;
    }
    printMatrix(room);
}

public static void releaseRooms(String [][]room, int x)
{
    int r, c;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {   
        out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = kb.nextLine();
        out.print("Enter the room number (row and column separated by a space) ");
        r=kb.nextInt();
        c=kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();
        while(r<0 || r>room.length || c<0 || c>room[r].length)
        {
            out.print("Invalid room number. Enter another room number (row and column separated by a space) ");
            r=kb.nextInt();
            c=kb.nextInt();
            kb.nextLine();
        }
        room[r][c] = "open";

    }
    printMatrix(room);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the semicolon on `else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));`

The `;` ends the statement which means the `break` is always done, not just when the condition is met.

Comment: Thank you so much. Those semicolons are always out to get me hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using

```
for(;;)
{
    out.print("Would you like to reserve or release a room? Type Q to exit ");
    a = kb.nextLine();

    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("reserve"))
    {
        out.print("How many rooms would you like to reserve? ");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
        reserveRooms(rooms, num);
    }
    else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("release"))
    {
        out.print("How many rooms would you like to release? ");
        int x = kb.nextInt();
        releaseRooms(rooms, x);
    }
    else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
        break;
}
```

why not use

```
while (!a.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
{
    out.print("Would you like to reserve or release a room? Type Q to exit ");
    a = kb.nextLine();

    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("reserve"))
    {
        out.print("How many rooms would you like to reserve? ");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
        reserveRooms(rooms, num);
    }
    else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("release"))
    {
        out.print("How many rooms would you like to release? ");
        int x = kb.nextInt();
        releaseRooms(rooms, x);
    }
    else 
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon `;`:

Change

```
else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
```

to

```
else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
```